# redirect domain to subdirectory via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i have a problem.

situation:
- old site in main directory with first .htaccess (`www.domain.com`)
- new site (joomla) in subdirectory /new with second .htaccess (`www.domain.com/new`)

what i need:
- on www.domain.com must be new site
- old site must be accessible via a direct link
- new site link must be `www.domain.com`, not `www.domain.com/new`

I tested probably every guide that I found but nothing works. the only thing I managed is redirected to a new page.

in first htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /new [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

second htaccess:
all off

please help me.
thx

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as rewriting every url that does not already point to a resource to that resource with the new prefix, unless it already has that prefix.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new/$1 [L]
```

Please note that you have to clear your cache since you used permanent redirects to test. Never test with permanent redirects. Instead use temporary redirects until you have verified everything works as expected.

Comment: thx you for your answer, but so far no change. cache is cleared. site: www.translating.sk

Comment: I am not sure how joomla works under the hood. It might just be a configuration issue. Googling suggests that you need to change a variable or 2 in `configuration.php`. (see here: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=252160 )

Comment: yes, i know. in conf is sef=0; sef_rewrite=0; sef_suffix=0;

Comment: @LubosBelan Did you take a look at the forum topic I edited into that comment?

Comment: yes, i read this post. no way, still same problem. all joomla sef module is off. second (subdirectory, joomla root dir) htaccess is off. redirect on domain.com/new works fine, but address is still domain.com/new. in configuration.php is set live_site=http://domain.com/new